# Code to Display Stacked Button

Tags: css, facebook, twitter

have the tweetmeme button on my site (http://SweatingTheBigStuff.com) and I want to add a facebook button BELOW it.

Right now the tweetmeme settings show:

```
float: right; margin-left: 10px;
```

What's the best Facebook plugin for this and what settings do I need?

I think the Simple Facebook Share Button should be good but I'm not sure the bit of code I should put to move it below the tweetmeme button.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me on our Wordpress Blog.

Twitter (TweetMeme Button) - wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tweetmeme/

clear:right; float:right; margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px;

Facebook Share (New) Button - wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-share-new/

float:right; position:relative; margin-left:10px;